# Sqlite Autoincrementing a field in a table

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a table **PatientRegistration** with Columns
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR,
PHONE TEXT,
AGE BLOB,
TURNNUMBER INT,
REG_DATE DATE TIME
I have been having troubles trying to automatically declare TURNNUMBER and assign it 0(zero) if it's null else increase it by +1 with respect to date, this is correct but only in SQL
**declare @turn tinyint,
@turn=isnull((select top 1 pa.turn from PatientRegistration pa where Day(pa.Reg_Date)=@day order by pa.ID desc),0)+1**
How can I achieve this using SQLite,,,, please

Edit: this should happen each a new patient is added

Comment: Use `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`.

Comment: Thanks for, I tried this but SQlite seems to not understand the "select top 1"

Comment: Can this be obtained using a trigger?

Comment: You need to stop using MS-SQL (T-SQL) syntax extensions and write ISO-compliant SQL. Use Sqlite’s online documentation to see what SQL constructs and syntax are supported.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the SQlite syntax correctly,,, only that I couldn't still solve the problem, no new turn number is inserted